# python, subprocess.call(["rm", "inv.mt0"], shell=True) not working

Tags: python, subprocess

friends,

I have a simple script

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["./run_xf"])

old=open('./inv.mt0','r')

lines=old.readlines()

lines=lines[3:]

new=open('./inv.mt1','w')

new.writelines(lines)

old.close()

new.close()

subprocess.call(["rm", "inv.mt0"], shell=True)
```

All the codes work except the last one.

run_xf runs hspice and generate inv.mt0. then i copy part of inv.mt0 to inv.mt1. then i want to delete inv.mt0. But this doesn't work.

For this specific example, it complains rm can't find operand. But if i write them together, it doesn't delete the file as well.

thanks

xf

Comment: "can't find operand": have you done anything to verify that inv.mt0 is there?

Comment: yes this may be the problem. how is the sequence between different commands here. Is it linear? run_xf generates inv.mt0.

Comment: it is linear. why is it so hard to verify if a file is there or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using `shell=True` you must pass a string to `subprocess.call`, not a list.  See http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call for more details.

However, invoking subprocess with `shell=True` is not recommended due to security implications.  You should remove `shell=True` and leave the list-style args.

Comment: Yes, i mentioned i tried

subprocess.call("rm inv.mt0", shell=True)

but it doesn't work

Comment: You could also try os.remove("inv.mt0").

Comment: Please add an os.listdir(".") and provide the output.  Do you see the "inv.mt0" file?  If not, it did not get created in that directory.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, gab. But i solved the problem not quite related to the command itself. Instead in run_xf, previously

hspice inv.sp &> log

now hspice inv.sp > log

without outputing things into the monitor from hspice, it seems working

Comment: It is there, the output from print os.listdir() is 
['run_xf', 'maxDelay.py', 'inv.mt0', 'scope.log', 'inv.sp', 'inv.tr0', 'make', 'inv.mt1', 'inv.ic0', 'inv.pa0', 'inv.st0', 'hehe', 'inv.tr1', 'log']